# java - classpath for libraries

Tags: java

I have compiled my java project in netbeans with multiple libraries and it's told me to execute the jar with the following parameters:

```
java -cp "D:\Documents\proj\lib\commons-net-3.1.jar;D:\Documents\proj\lib\org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar;D:\Documents\proj\lib\prompt.jar;D:\Documents\proj\lib\zip4j_1.3.2.jar;D:\Documents\proj\dist\Myprogram.jar" pack.Myprogram_GUI
```

but if I move the folder or try to use this on another computer without the exact same path the program wont load and nor will the libraries. So is there a way to define a kind of root folder? so instead of typing D:\Documents\proj\lib\commons-net-3.1.jar I could just type lib\commons-net-3.1.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Java 6 or later, classpath wildcards are a part of the JVM. You can use relative path using

```
java -cp ".;.\lib\*" pack.Myprogram_GUI
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create `$PROJECT_HOME` as a system environment variable and use it with the path:

```
java -cp "$PROJECT_HOME\lib\commons-net-3.1.jar;$PROJECT_HOME\lib\org.eclipse.swt-3.1.jar;...
```

Comment: I am wanting to release this program so others can use it, wouldn't I have to create the system environment variable on each computer before starting the program?

Comment: Well actually you would... Usually there's an installation script that sets up the environment during the installation. One of the things this installation script should do is set `$PROJECT_HOME` variable.